# setTimeout with text AND <img src>? getting [object Object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, image, settimeout

Im trying to set useState/timeout to display text and an icon image after 5 seconds, text is fine but i want to be able to also have an image:

```js
import slackbot from '../../public/images/slackbot.png'

const [text, setText] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    setText( {slackbot} + 'this will be the slackbot auto message' )
  }, 3000)
}, [])
```

attempting to add it in the use State set Text as shown above but leaves me with an [object Object] display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely don't need to add the image source to the state string (and in fact that won't work). Here's a potential solution: just store the text in state and conditionally show the text and image if that text is set.

```
import slackbot from "../../public/images/slackbot.png";

function Component() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setText("this will be the slackbot auto message");
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {text && (
        <>
          <img src={slackbot} /> {text}
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, there is an issue with the way you are concatenating the slackbot image variable with the text string. Instead of concatenating the image variable correctly, you are wrapping it inside curly braces ({slackbot}), which will result in an object representation of the image.

To fix the issue, you need to update the concatenation in the setText function call.
So just do this in your set state function:

```
setText( slackbot + 'this will be the slackbot auto message' )
```

Comment: I think the OP simply left out some of the React code.

Comment: @Pointy I think so too, I have taken out the first part leaving only the fix to the issue.